# SSLStream - Certificado

Tags: c#, certificado-digital, sslstream

**1** - Para fazer uma comunicação segura entre um cliente e um servidor, resolvi utilizar SSL utilizando SSLStream, a partir do [exemplo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.net.security.sslstream(v=vs.110).aspx) do site msdn, mas a questão é que não é um servidor na web, mesmo não sendo um servidor web eu tenho que utilizar um certificado, ou posso abrir mão??

**2** - Caso precise, como posso obter esse certificado? Sei que não é pago nem nada do tipo.

**3** - É viável eu fazer o meu próprio? Caso sim, como posso fazer um?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim pode utilizar o `SSLStream` mesmo que não seja um servidor Web, i.e, pode usa-lo quando estabelecer uma ligação TCP entre um servidor e um cliente.

Pode gerar o seu próprio certificado com o [OpenSSL](https://www.openssl.org/related/binaries.html) [(guia para criar um certificado auto assinado em OpenSSL)](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#cert-self).

De forma a facilitar o processo, fica um pedaço de código que gera um certificado através da linha de comandos (recomendo criar um .cmd/.bat para facilitar o processo):

```
:: Se instalou o OpenSSL num local não-padrão, altere os caminhos abaixo.

@echo off
set OPENSSL_CONF=C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl.cfg

"C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl" req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -subj /C=[código de duas letras do país]/ST=[estado]/L=[localidade]/CN=[Nome do servidor] -newkey rsa:1024 -keyout private.key -out cert.crt

"C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin\openssl" pkcs12 -export -in cert.crt -inkey private.key -out [nome do certificado].pfx -passout pass:[password do seu certificado]

del .rnd
del private.key
del cert.crt
```

Com o certificado criado, pode utiliza-lo da seguinte forma no servidor:

```
X509Certificate2 cert = new X509Certificate2([caminho para o certificado, [password do certificado]);
SslStream sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream());
sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(cert);
```

Notas:
[(Documentação do AuthenticateAsServer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.security.sslstream.authenticateasserver%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: a utilização do openssl é melhor? No caso eu quero estabelecer uma conexão, criptografar os dados e enviar para meu servidor

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi melhor implica a comparação com alguma coisa. Melhor do que o quê? O OpenSSL é grátis e facilita o trabalho. Se estiver a considerar utilizar um certificado em cenários onde a segurança é bastante importante, pode considerar comprar um certificado criado e assinado por uma empresa credenciada (tipo [GlobalSign](https://www.globalsign.co.uk/) et al)

Comment: a parte de facilitar o trabalho, como ele facilita?

Comment: digo facilitar, no sentido de que, tirando o tempo de instalação, consegue gerar um certificado em poucos segundos para utilizar durante o desenvolvimento/testes, etc

Comment: no caso, posso utilizar o próprio código da msdn, fazendo somente a alteração no X509Certificate para o X509Certificate2 com os parâmetros corretos?

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi No exemplo do msdn tem de fornecer um certificado ao programa (no servidor). Se reparar a linha serverCertificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certificate); cria um certificado baseado num certificado existente.

Comment: sim, no caso ele trás como parâmetro o nome do certificado, então eu gero ele com o .bat, e já utilizo no X509Certificate2, certo?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15006/discussion-between-omni-and-enzo-tiezzi).

Comment: agora ele me da um erro que não acha o nome do arquivo(certificado) sendo que está na mesma pasta

Comment: se estiver a utilizar o serverCertificate = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certificate) tem de lhe passar o ficheiro .cer e não o .pfx (veja [esta](http://stackoverflow.com/a/900052/1242661) resposta do SO)

Comment: estou utilizando assim: serverCertificate = new X509Certificate2("TesteFbmCertificate","fbm12345");

Comment: ele me da um cryptographicException