# Excepção ao tentar autenticar ligação SSL

Tags: c#, sslstream

No meu cliente ao tentar autenticar uma ligação SSL é levantada uma excepção do tipo `AuthenticationException`. Os erros encontrados no certificado são `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch`e `RemoteCertificateChainErrors`.

O código utilizado para autenticar:

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient(serverName);
```

Como posso resolver esta excepção?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vamos dividir o problema em partes.

Relativamente ao erro `RemoteCertificateNameMismatch`, isto deve-se ao facto de que o nome que deve passar no `AuthenticateAsClient(...)` é o nome do servidor. Ou seja, se o servidor for o `localhost`, deverá passar esse nome desta forma:

```
sslStream.AuthenticateAsClient("localhost");
```

Caso esteja a gerar o seu próprio certificado, tem de garantir que o nome que passa ao `AuthenticateAsClient` é o mesmo que está na opção "CN=[nome do servidor]".

Relativamente ao `RemoteCertificateChainErrors`, caso esteja a gerar o seu próprio certificado, o algoritmo que valida o certificado pode não confiar no seu certificado dado que este não se encontra numa localização segura.

Uma forma de resolver o problema é instalar o certificado na *certificate store* do seu computador ou então usar o seguinte código (fonte: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dd633677%28v=exchg.80%29.aspx)):

```
private static bool CertificateValidationCallBack(
     object sender,
     System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate certificate,
     System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Chain chain,
     System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors)
{
  // If the certificate is a valid, signed certificate, return true.
  if (sslPolicyErrors == System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.None)
  {
    return true;
  }

  // If there are errors in the certificate chain, look at each error to determine the cause.
  if ((sslPolicyErrors & System.Net.Security.SslPolicyErrors.RemoteCertificateChainErrors) != 0)
  {
    if (chain != null && chain.ChainStatus != null)
    {
      foreach (System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatus status in chain.ChainStatus)
      {
        if ((certificate.Subject == certificate.Issuer) &&
           (status.Status == System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.UntrustedRoot))
        {
          // Self-signed certificates with an untrusted root are valid. 
          continue;
        }
        else
        {
          if (status.Status != System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ChainStatusFlags.NoError)
          {
            // If there are any other errors in the certificate chain, the certificate is invalid,
         // so the method returns false.
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
    }

    // When processing reaches this line, the only errors in the certificate chain are 
// untrusted root errors for self-signed certificates. These certificates are valid
// for default Exchange server installations, so return true.
    return true;
  }
  else
  {
 // In all other cases, return false.
    return false;
  }
}
```

Desta forma, é possível utilizar certificados assinados por si enquanto está a desenvolver/testar. Para o utilizar na validação:

```
SslStream stream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false, CertificateValidationCallBack);
```

Desta forma, quando for criado o `stream` o método acima é utilizado para fazer a verificação.

Comment: quando eu fiz o certificado não tem nenhum "CN=[servidor]"

Comment: caso esteja a usar o OpenSSL, é o `Common Name` que ele pede quando está a gerar o certificado. Editei o código do .bat da sua outra [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/20766/sslstream-certificado/20768#20768) de forma a eliminar a necessidade de especificar os nomes de cada vez que corre o script.

Comment: sim sim, to usando oque você mesmo me passou ontem

Comment: como eu coloco no AuthenticateAsClient() então o nome?

Comment: se no CN colocar `localhost`, o método fica `AuthenticateAsClient("localhost");`

Comment: UserCertificateValidationCallback é uma classe com o método CertificateValidationCallBack?

Comment: não, `CertificateValidationCallBac`k é um método que define no seu programa e depois utiliza no constructor do SSLStream (peço desculpa por eventuais incoerências no código, vou rever quando estiver em casa).

Comment: arrumei direitinho aqui, a minha dúvida ainda é sobre o CN, porque no caso no bat que você me passou ontem não tinha o "CN=[nome servidor]"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15033/discussion-between-omni-and-enzo-tiezzi).

Comment: caso não seja localhost, eu posso colocar somente o nome da máquina correto ?

Comment: @EnzoTiezzi tem de passar o nome que colocou no CN quando gerou o certificado. Se no CN pôs o nome da máquina, então passe o nome da máquina ao `AuthenticateAsClient(...)`

Comment: esse CN, eu coloco quando abre o prompt pra fazer o certificado?